# How to count collection items array which is depend on condition?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array of data which is given below. And i have attached screenshot of `dd($data['attendances'])` output here. I use for loop to count but its not working. The question is, how can i count collection items which have `registered = 'no'`? Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
    $data = [
        'employee'    => $employee,
        'attendances' => $attendances,
        'filter'      => $filter,
        'no_records'  => "No Records",
        'weekend'     => "Weekly Off"
    ];

    for ( $i=0; $i <= count($data['attendances']); $i++ ){
        if ($data['attendances'][$i]['registered'] = 'no'){
            echo count($data['attendances'][$i]['registered']);
        }
    }

//  dd($data['attendances']);
```

Above code `for` loop gives an error which is:

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements
> Countable

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count all collection items that have `registered` to `no`:

```php
dd($data['attendances']->where('registered', 'no')->count());
```

You can find all collection manipulation methods in the documentation, here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods

In this case, we first use `->where` to filter the collection (taking only items with `registered` to `no`) then we use the `count` method to count how many there are.

Comment: No problem, I updated my answer with some explanations and additional info. Have a nice day

Comment: not sure `count(array($data['attendances']));`